# RegExp pattern for alphanumeric with underscore or hypen

Tags: php, regex

I searched & tried below RegExp, but, not working for my requirement. Please, provide PHP RegExp, which accepts at least one alphanumeric and optional underscore or hyphen, but, Underscore or Hyphen should not repeat twice in a row.

```
/^([a-z0-9]+-)*[a-z0-9]+$/i
```

**Example formats**

1. _test147
2. test
3. _a
4. test_test
5. test-test_, etc

Comment: Are you sure a regex is best suited for this? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

You may use this regex in ignore case mode:

```sh
^[-_]?[a-z\d]+(?:[_-][a-z\d]+)*[-_]?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gNt5L7/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `[-_]?`: Match an *optional* `_` or `-`
- `[a-z\d]+`: Match 1+ of alphanumeric character
- `(?:`: Start a non-capture group

  - `[_-]`: Match a `_` or `-`
  - `[a-z\d]+`: Match 1+ of alphanumeric character
- `)*`: End non-capture group. Repeat this group 0 or more times
- `[-_]?`: Match an *optional* `_` or `-`
- `$`: End

Or else if you want even better performance then use this possessive quantifier regex:

```
^[-_]?[a-z\d]++(?:[_-][a-z\d]+)*[-_]?+$
```

Comment: @Raj: Did this work out?

Answer (score 0):

```
/^([-_]?[a-z0-9]+)+[-_]?$/i
```

This has a repeating sequence with an optional hyphen or underscore followed by alphanumerics, and then allows another optional hyphen or underscore at the end.

Comment: Because of optional `[-_]?` in a repeating group it will take lot more steps

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Comment: @anubhava: but if you change the capture group to an atomic group it is faster. Whatever this one wins: https://regex101.com/r/OK4bqq/1

Comment: Unless we're dealing with very long inputs, I doubt it matters. That's what I mean about premature optimization. I write what looks simplest.